# How to draw 2D UIView from coordinates from SceneKit?

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit

[image]So I'm developing an app which uses both ARKit and SceneKit. The idea of the app is to calculate area and to draw 2D plan of room. In every corner of room I add sphere node, each of the nodes has its own X, Z, and Y coordinates, so I have coordinates of every corner. Now I need to use those corner coordinates and draw a plan of a room. I need to make 2D UIView model out of X and Z coordinate (ignoring Y coordinate).

My question is how to use X and Z coordinates of corners and make UIView plan of room?

Example of sphere coordinates:

Sphere 1:
x: 0.017605
z: -0.110372
y: -0.261535

Sphere 2:
x: 0.0278791
z: -0.152639
y: -0.252484

Sphere 3:
x: 0.0631846
z: -0.125349
y: -0.254902

Comment: Are you asking about the calculations, or the programming side of things?

Comment: @George_E_2 I'm asking about how to program drawing plan from given coordinates. I added examples of coordinates, we have to drop y coordinate and draw a room plan from x and z coordinates.

Comment: So you want a top view of a room??

Comment: @AlokSubedi basically yes

Comment: have you tried any thing?? I think multiplying coordinate with 10000 and using as pixel might work. But it needs lots of calculation.

Comment: @AlokSubedi I haven't tried anything yet. but i like your idea and I'll give it try